# Unable to unmarshal DeployerCapability property: strategy

Tags: discovery-service

I'm in the process of upgrading my services from 8.1.1 to 8.5, and I have discovered that when attempting to register my capabilities, I get an ODataUnmarshelling exception with the following:

> Caused by: com.sdl.odata.api.unmarshaller.ODataUnmarshallingException: The request body contains a property that does not exist in the structured type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.DeployerCapability, property: strategy

In my storage config, the deployer capability is configured as follows:

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost:9084/httpupload">
    <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
</Role>
```

So where is the strategy coming from and why doesn't the discovery-registration tool understand it? I had a poke around in the discovery database, but couldn't find anything likely in there.

Comment: Is the discovery-registration tool is also 8.5 ? strategy is new config option added for deployer capability config.

Comment: You nailed it. Another victim of the unfortunate "xcopy upgrade" strategy. I copied the jar over from the release zip and it's working fine again. Still puzzled about where the property was coming from though. Anyway - if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use 8.5 discovery registration tool against 8.5 discovery service.

In 8.5, Deployer capability entity has additional configuration point (strategy) which is used to configure multiple deployer end point. Due to this change in entity data model, 8.5 registration tool is required.